# How to avoid connecting two different webapp accounts with one social account

Tags: spring, spring-social

I'm using Spring Social to connect user application account to a social account (Facebook and/or Twitter).

It turns out that it is possible that two different user accounts connect to the same social account.

Example:

- User1 in my webapp connects with Facebook account #1
- User2 in my webapp connects with Facebook account #1

This is possible now. Looks like this happens inside Spring Social.
After that, sign-in with social account is not possible for both accounts.

I would like to avoid connecting same social account to different webapp users at a point when User2 tries to connect. Any hint how can I do that is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer to this question is providede [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?129207-One-connection-to-multiple-users).
Code example [here](https://github.com/socialsignin/spring-social-security/blob/master/src/main/java/org/socialsignin/springsocial/security/signin/EnsureUniqueConnectInterceptor.java).

In short, ConnectInterceptor must be used for ConnectController to check for existing connection and remove currently creating connection if its a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default connection controller provided by spring social, after getting the user token/secret it stores in database. To store in database spring-social uses :

- `org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcConnectionRepository`
- `org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository`

Before storing into database you can validate the items and provide your own logic.

Hope this helps!